# Updating three category tables and setting category mapping with MySQL in one Query/Transaction

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-update, insert-update

I have three tables;

```
masterCat
category
subCat
```

Master cat simply has two columns `id` and `name`

The subsequent tables have three columns, `id`, `name` and `mapsTo`

Fairly obviously, the `mapsTo` column in the `category` table indicates which `masterCat` this category belongs to, thus creating a hierarchical category structure

I am trying to write a script to enable users to update and amend their categories, including adding new ones.

So, if a new structure is created:

```
newMasterCat > newCategory > newSubCategory
```

How can I write this in MySQL without having so many lines of code, this is what it needs to do:

1. Create the new rows in each table (3 inserts as one transaction,
           no problem)
2. Look back to those rows, and find out the ID assigned to the `masterCat` and `category` table amendment.
3. update the new rows in `category` and `subCat` with the ID of the records created in their parent tables

I can do this in three stages, but is there a quicker way?

(Using a MySQL database and MySQL drivers in VB.net)

Comment: Are the ID fields auto-incrementing?  If so, I think you need to do it in three steps.

Comment: Yes they are, really, there's no MySQL magic that I havent come across to this in one hit?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to accomplish this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

The result of this function is scoped to the current connection and will not be impacted by other concurrent inserts. So your inserts will look like:

```
INSERT INTO masterCat (name) VALUES ('masterCat1');

INSERT INTO category (name, mapsTo) VALUES ('Cat1', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

And finally you can chain this a third time in the same way:

```
INSERT INTO subCat (name, mapsTo) VALUES ('SubCat1', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Someone can comment to how these statements can be executed in VB.NET, but you *may* have to create a stored procedure to execute separate statements in a single call - i.e. you may not be able to just chain those in a call to something like `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

As an aside I would note - a lot of people spend a lot of time worried about preventing multiple DB round trips when this is by order of magnitude not the bottleneck they should be concerned with.

Comment: That looks useful, thanks. Appreciate your point that this isn't going to really be creating a  bottleneck, just looking to simplify code all the time. Reading that link, there's no need to specify which table we want that `LAST_INSERT_ID` from? That's clever! :)

Comment: It will pull the last id created during the current connection. It is awesome, but I also assumed I had to specify the table the first time I used it and had to re-read when I couldn't see where to do it :)